# Pandas: Index the first element of each list in a dataframe column of lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a Series of lists and would like to index the first element of each list in a data frame of lists using pandas. How can I do this?

**Working example**

My original dataset is a pandas data frame that looks like:

```
# Import raw dataset from URL
url = 'http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data'
column_names = ['MPG', 'Cylinders', 'Displacement', 'Horsepower', 
                'Weight', 'Acceleration', 'Model Year', 'Origin', 'Carname']
train = pd.read_csv(url, names=column_names,
                          na_values='?',sep='\s+'
                          , skipinitialspace=True)

temp1 = pd.DataFrame(train["Carname"].str.split())
print(temp1)

                            Carname
0                 [plymouth, champ]
1                    [amc, matador]
2     [chevroelt, chevelle, malibu]
...                             ...
1489         [vw, dasher, (diesel)]
1490                [honda, accord]
1491             [ford, escort, 4w]
```

The desired result for this would be something like,

```
    'plymouth'
    'amc'
    'chevroelt'
    .....
```

Comment: Use `.str` accessor. `s.str[0]`

Comment: This was not working on my original dataset. @Psidom

Comment: Please explain how it's not working.

Comment: ` 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'
` @Psidom

Comment: Your title says it's a Series not a DataFrame.

Comment: Ok, I have fixed that @Psidom

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237711/discussion-between-user4933-and-psidom).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the string accessor `.str[]`, as follows:

```
temp1['Carname'].str[0]         # str[0] for first element in list
```

**Result:**

```
0      chevrolet
1          buick
2       plymouth
3            amc
4           ford
         ...    
393         ford
394           vw
395        dodge
396         ford
397        chevy
Name: Carname, Length: 398, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a function to the series that selects the first element of each series item, resulting in a new series:

```py
s_first_elements = s.apply(lambda x: x[0])
```

Comment: Hi @Arne , this is giving me the first list not the first element of each list `Carname    [plymouth, champ]`

Comment: It is based on your minimum working example, where the series values are lists, not strings.

Comment: I added my original dataset and how I Loaded it. @Arne